# Query returns unexpected value

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I use the following query SQLite is returning the following:

[image]

So as TotalSafeSanitationServices2000 goes from, say, 80 - 79 the next value in descending order will be 8. The data type is set to TEXT and I assume this is why, but from what I've read data type is less important in SQLite, but it is more difficult to change.

Is there a simple solution to this?

I am using DB browser for SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting rules are different from strings and numbers; string-wise, `'89'` is less than `'9'` (because it starts with `'8'`, which is less than `'9'`).

You can `CAST()` your strings to numbers for sorting:

```
order by cast(TotalSafeSanitationService2000 as integer)
```

I would suggest modifying your data structure to store numbers as numbers. You are starting to see the problems that arise when not using the correct datatype (there are more to come such as artithmetic operations). SQLite has limited functionalities to modify a table, so you would need to recreate it, move the data, and drop the old one.